# Editor between Davinci and Capcut?

Tags: davinci-resolve, recommendation

Would you say Davinci Resolve is too advanced for the editing of shorts? Are there any other high quality yet simplistic editors you'd suggest that provide a lot of resources without paying? I've heard capcut is pretty good, and I even tried it for a while, yet in the free version, (which is the only version I've used) I felt like more advanced edits weren't available to me. Basically I'm asking about a free editing service in a level between both of them.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say Davinci is too advanced for a YouTube short, but the workflows are more optimized for bigger projects. To simplify it, skip the media page and go straight to the edit page. Then, drag your footage into the media pool. Pretty much all you'll need is the edit page, the color page (for basic correction), and the deliver page for exporting. Once you get to know how to set up the project settings, it's pretty straightforward from there. You will just need to set your timeline resolution to a 9:16 aspect ratio or 1080x1920 (most are already presets in the dropdown menu). For other editors, I'm not sure what would be free, but I think that since Resolve is free, it might be worth learning when it could become a useful skill in the future if you ever end up doing some more complex projects. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

> Is Resolve too advanced, (vs. Capcut)?

No. **I would say they are different types of editors**. One "feature" of Capcut-like editors is the template library.

Resolve has some libraries, like different styles to add text lower thirds and credits. You can get third-party libraries but it does not offer one by itself.

So, if what you need are those kind of templates, probably **Canva**. (The same case, a free limited version)

One editor that I used to recommend (that was pretty good) actually changed the business model, from editor alone to be part of a library. **Hit Film** is now part of Artist. It has a basic free plan.

> I felt like more advanced edits weren't available to me.

What features? You need to define your specific needs, probably the software has them and you have not found them.

---

But if you are asking about free alternative software, as software, not services (which would include templates, assets, and cloud storage) Yes, there are several (besides the already mentioned). Look for Open source projects, like **ShotCut** And **OpenShot**.

Another one that has a free version, and a bit of a different interface is **VSDC**.

But, personally, I would stick to **DaVinci Resolve**. You do not need an OP computer to run it. And it is one of the best.

One open-source software to check is **Blender**. You could explore it as a simple video editor, but as an entry point to explore it as the 3D suite that it is.